# Is it realistic to get a SQL statement with multiple JOINs and no WHERE clause retrieving 8000 rows under 1s?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I'm working on page that summarizes the decks, win rates and other data regarding Magic cards at https://pennydreadfulmagic.com/seasons/all/cards/

The main SQL query frequently takes more than 10s on production (less on my laptop but still >5s). The server is a standard Linode box running openSUSE and the database is MariaDB (MySQL).

I'm trying to work out if running this query on user time when the page is requested is a foolish idea or if I just need the right optimizations to make it work in less than a second.

A naïve version of the query is:

```
SELECT
    card,
    COUNT(*) AS num_decks,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.games > IFNULL(odm.games, 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.games < odm.games THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS losses,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.games = odm.games THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draws
FROM
    deck_card AS dc
INNER JOIN
    deck AS d ON dc.deck_id = d.id
INNER JOIN
    deck_match AS dm ON d.id = dm.deck_id
INNER JOIN
    deck_match AS odm ON dm.match_id = odm.match_id AND dm.deck_id <> odm.deck_id
GROUP BY
    dc.card
ORDER BY
    num_decks DESC,
    card
```

There are approximately this many rows in each table:

```
deck_card - 470,000 (DISTINCT card = 8,500)
deck - 20,000
match - 35,000
deck_match - 70,000
```

These don't seem like very big numbers for SQL to deal with which is why I want to know if it's realistic to make this query run significantly faster.

EXPLAIN says:

```
+--------+-----+-------+------------------------+-------------------------------+-----+----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | type   | tbl | type  | possible_keys          | key                    | len | ref                  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+------+--------+-----+-------+------------------------+------------------------+-----+----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE | d   | index | PRIMARY                | person_id              | 4   | NULL                 | 18888 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE | dm  | ref   | match_id,deck_id       | deck_id                | 4   | decksite.d.id        |     1 |                                              |
|    1 | SIMPLE | odm | ref   | match_id               | match_id               | 4   | decksite.dm.match_id |     1 | Using where                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE | dc  | ref   | deck_id_card_sideboard | deck_id_card_sideboard | 4   | decksite.d.id        |    10 | Using index                                  |
+------+--------+-----+-------+------------------------+------------------------+-----+----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a somewhat faster version of the query (that is still too slow) where I pull the match/deck_card stuff out into a subquery that is then joined to the main query which I've left out here as it's harder to understand. This does make things incrementally faster but nothing close to the ideal speed.

I'm not necessarily looking to be spoon-fed the optimizations required here (although that would be nice too!) so much as to understand if it is realistic to run queries like this on user time with the right optimizations? Or should I put my time into finding the right caching strategy or denormalizing the database?

---

CREATE TABLEs are as follows:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE deck_card;
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| deck_card | CREATE TABLE `deck_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deck_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `card` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `n` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sideboard` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `deck_card_deck_id_card_sideboard` (`deck_id`,`card`,`sideboard`),
  KEY `idx_card` (`card`),
  KEY `idx_card_deck_id_sideboard_n` (`card`,`deck_id`,`sideboard`,`n`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_card_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`deck_id`) REFERENCES `deck` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39407094 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE deck;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| deck  | CREATE TABLE `deck` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `identifier` varchar(190) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `competition_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `archetype_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_uri` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `featured_card` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `small_thumbnail_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `finish` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `decklist_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `retired` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `reviewed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `deck_source_id_identifier` (`source_id`,`identifier`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`),
  KEY `competition_id` (`competition_id`),
  KEY `archetype_id` (`archetype_id`),
  KEY `deck_hash` (`decklist_hash`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `source` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`competition_id`) REFERENCES `competition` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`archetype_id`) REFERENCES `archetype` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21460 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE deck_match;
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| deck_match | CREATE TABLE `deck_match` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deck_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `games` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`),
  KEY `deck_id` (`deck_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_match_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`deck_id`) REFERENCES `deck` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `deck_match_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `match` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73857 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Seeing temporary/filesort is where the pain comes in. Computed columns like that are also murder on performance. Can you pre-compute those win/loss values and have them already stored in the database?

Comment: So in general you'd say some kind of denormalization/caching would be the "usual" or "correct" solution for this kind of query? There's no secret SQL magic that I don't know with INDEXes and JOINs that's going to magically bring it in in 100ms? :D I can certainly recalculate these values on a regular schedule or upon each write of a new match. I was hoping to avoid that for code simplicity but if it's the normal approach I feel better about it :)

Comment: A little bit of tactical denormalization can go a long way. Computed values are always the first suspect in terms of performance problems. Second is lack of indexes. Third is the IO capabilities of the server (e.g. HDD vs SSD) and the database configuration. There's a lot of ways you can tune your server to give it considerably more memory than the default config permits.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  It is hard to see what indexes you have.  And "computed columns"??

Comment: Edited to add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to add. No 'computed columns' as it stands. Very happy to add indexes that help! There's not much data and happy to punish writes to speed up reads.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Can you tell whether the query is CPU-bound versus I/O-bound?

Comment: 3.8GB RAM, 4GB swap. innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728. mysqld is frequently at 100% CPU or above so I'd assume CPU-bound but not sure how to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the "right" answers?  Or are the numbers bigger than they should be?  The latter happens with the "explode-implode" that occurs when doing `JOIN`, then `GROUP BY`.

See what happens if you change

```
FROM deck_card AS dc
```

to

```
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT card FROM deck_card ) AS dc
```

Comment: I get the right answers. It just takes longer than I'd like. 4-5s on dev and longer on prod. After a reasonable amount of wrangling I started to think that maybe what I am trying to compute is just not something that should be done on user time.

I can't do the SELECT DISTINCT thing because `deck` is joined to the query via `dc.deck_id` which is no longer present. `FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT card, deck_id FROM deck_card ) AS dc` takes longer.

Comment: It takes 10s on production. I have total control over the database so even restructuring data to make this easier is an option. I hate that folks have to wait 15s for the "all time" card page!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly fix this but I did improve the performance of this part of my application from about 10s to less than 1s.

I used a query like the above but "bucketed" by day (`GROUP BY card, DATE(d.created_date)`) to create a `_card_stats` table offline which I regenerate on a regular basis. When I want this data I can now much more quickly aggregate for last week/season/all time from the bucketed table.

Not what I was dreaming of but fairly workable at the cost of a little complexity/lag in updates.